# find the part of the where clause that cause return in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I have a mysql query that is like so,

```
SELECT USER
FROM   users
WHERE  user_name = someUserName
        OR location = someLocation
        OR deleted = 1 
LIMIT 1
```

I am trying to figure out which one of the where cases caused a user to be selected.  Is this possible to do?

Comment: I don't understand your question. In your SQL request, `WHERE user_name = someUserName` does the selection of all records with the value `someUserName` in the column `user_name`.  Please edit your question if this is not what you want to know.

Comment: someUserName is just a variable

Comment: Ok, I didn't see you had `OR` in the `WHERE` before it was reformatted. I apologize for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometime I'm debugging something and I'd like to be able to answer the same kinds of questions. Obviously you can comment out parts of the query and run it that way. If you're not sure about an expression or nulls or you just want to confirm your sanity then you might just try a case expression.

```
SELECT
    user
    case when user_name = someUserName then 'true' else 'false' end as Condition1,
    case when location  = someLocation then 'true' else 'false' end as Condition2,
    case when deleted   = 1 then 'true' else 'false' end as Condition 3
FROM users
WHERE
        user_name = someUserName
    OR  location = someLocation
    OR  deleted = 1 
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

By selecting the filtering column's you can find which one worked.

```
SELECT USER,
       user_name,
       location,
       deleted,
       CASE
         WHEN user_name = someUserName
              AND location <> someLocation
              AND deleted <> 1 THEN 'User_name'
         WHEN location = someLocation
              AND user_name <> someUserName
              AND deleted <> 1 THEN 'location'
         WHEN location <> someLocation
              AND user_name <> someUserName
              AND deleted = 1 THEN 'deleted'
         WHEN user_name = someUserName
              AND location = someLocation
              AND deleted <> 1 THEN 'User_name,location'
         WHEN user_name = someUserName
              AND location <> someLocation
              AND deleted = 1 THEN 'User_name,deleted'
         WHEN user_name <> someUserName
              AND location = someLocation
              AND deleted = 1 THEN 'location,deleted'
         WHEN user_name = someUserName
              AND location = someLocation
              AND deleted = 1 THEN 'ALL'
       END AS Filer_Column
FROM   users
WHERE  user_name = someUserName
        OR location = someLocation
        OR deleted = 1 
LIMIT 1
```

Also `Limit` with out `order by` doesn't make any sense to me. Better to add the order in which you want to limit the result set

Comment: But that will return all the columns of the user that is present from the query, so I can't tell which where clause did it

Comment: But that is only allowing for 1 case to show there are times when two things can be true, is there a way to scale this?

Comment: Unfortunately those conditions will break once nulls enter the picture.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to indicate all conditions met if more than one you could approach the problem like this:

```
select user, group_concat(condition_met) as conditions_met
  from (select user, 'A' as condition_met
          from users
         where user_name = someusername
        union all
        select user, 'B'
          from users
         where location = someLocation
        union all
        select user, 'C'
          from users
         where deleted = 1) x
 group by user
```

This should be functionally equivalent:

```
select user,
       sum(user_name = someusername) as cond_a,
       sum(location = someLocation) as cond_b,
       sum(deleted = 1)) as as cond_c
  from users
 where user_name = someusername
    or location = somelocation
    or deleted = 1
 group by user
```

Comment: But it is not necessarily all conditions met it may be 1 condition met, or 2 or all conditions met

Comment: @johsmith I understand that... this would show 'A,B' if the first 2 conditions are met, 'A' if only the first is met, 'A,B,C' if all are met...

Comment: is there a way to do this without using four selects? I am trying to minimize the number of queries

Comment: Query I added will show 1 in the cond_a/b/c columns if the corresponding condition is met.